# Finding first matching sibling element while traversing the DOM

Tags: xpath, siblings

I am trying to create an xpath expression that will find the first matching sibling 'down' the dom given an initial sibling (note: initial siblings will be Tom and Steve). For example, I want to find 'jerry1' under the 'Tom' tr. I have looked into the following-sibling argument, but I'm not sure that's the best approach for this? Any ideas?

```
<tr>
     <a title=”Tom”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry1”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry2”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry3”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”Steve”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry1”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry2”/>
</tr>
<tr>
     <a title=”jerry3”/>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

`following-sibling` will work.  This will select the `a` node with the title "jerry1":

`//a[@title='Tom']/../following-sibling::tr/a`

The `/..` traverses up to Tom's parent `<tr>`, then `following-sibling` to the next `<tr>`, then finally the `<a>` node within that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how does this command find the 'jerry1' node without specifying it, so how would this find the element jerry3 under the Tom sibling?

Comment: 'jerry3' is not "the first matching sibling 'down' the dom given an initial sibling [of 'Tom']", as you phrased the question.  The code I posted gives you the next `<a>` in document order given an initial `<a>`.  Do you need something different?

Comment: After reading my post I guess I missed that point. I need to be able to select 'any' of the first matching siblings under the Target node. So given the target 'Tom' and 'Jerry2', I would need an xpath to find the 'jerry2' instance that is a sibling under 'tom'

Comment: @Jason In that case just add an attribute match to the end so the xpath looks like: `//a[@title='Tom']/../following-sibling::tr/a[@title='jerry2']`

Comment: @Jason Also, to get only the first matching 'jerry2' put the first part in parens with a `[1]` at the end:  `(//a[@title='Tom']/../following-sibling::tr/a[@title='jerry2'])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Following XPath worked for me:

```
(//a[@title='Tom']/parent::*/following-sibling::tr/a[@title= 'jerry1'])[1]
```

First matching `a` with `title` jerry1 following a `tr` with an `a`-child with `title` Tom.
Starting  at `a[@title='Tom']`, going to the parent tr with `/parent` , selecting  all following sibling tr-nodes with `::*/following-sibling::tr`, that have an `/a[@title= 'jerry1']` as child node. Because this would select 2 `jerry1`-nodes and the first jerry1 following Tom is searched, selecting the first one by wrapping the XPath with `()` and choosing the first match with `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath statement finds the first `tr` element that has an `a` with the `@title` "jerry1" that is a following-sibling of the `tr` element that has an `a` with the `@title` of "Tom"

```
//tr[a/@title='Tom']/following-sibling::tr[a/@title='jerry1'][1]
```